# ZeroMQ + Java performance on pub/sub

Tags: java, performance, zeromq, publish-subscribe

Googled without luck, my problem is as the title. I got only around 50K message per second for some < 64 bytes message, with only a simple pub/sub test sending a const string through. The same box demonstrates quite stable performance regardless if I am doing TCP:// or INPROC://, or under Windows or Ubuntu.

The hardware and software configuration is:

i5-4670 3.4G x 4 Core

16GB 1666Mhz RAM

Windows 7 64bit

JDK 1.8.05

ZeroMQ 3.2.3

jzmq 2.2.2

And the sample program is as below where I created 2 threads, 1 doing pub and 1 doing sub. Delivering the message 1000 times and wait till the subscriber receive them all. The performance is constantly around 30 ms, which is only 1/10 of the performance I assume ZeroMQ should deliver. The code demonstrates same performance running stand-alone in IDE and running as a JUnit test.

Could anyone give me some hint on this?

EDIT1: Seems if I enlarge the message count to 5000 I got a core dump from JVM. That looks to me a hint to the real problem, though I don't think I got anything wrong in the threading model. What can be the culprit?

```
public class ZMQReadynessTest {

private ZMQ.Context context;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    ZMQLoader.initialize();
    context = ZMQ.context(2);
}

@Test
public void testSimpleMessage() {
    final int totalCount = 1000;
    String topic = "tcp://127.0.0.1:31216";
    final CountDownLatch startLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(totalCount);

    // create a simple subscriber
    final ZMQ.Socket subscribeSocket = context.socket(ZMQ.SUB);
    subscribeSocket.connect(topic);
    subscribeSocket.subscribe("TestTopic".getBytes());

    Thread subThread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    fail();
                }

                startLatch.countDown();
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(100);

                while (latch.getCount() > 0) {

                    // get the message
                    int count = 0;
                    if ((count = subscribeSocket.recvZeroCopy(buffer, buffer.remaining(), 0)) > 0) {

                        // another receive for content
                        count = subscribeSocket.recvZeroCopy(buffer, buffer.remaining(), 0);
                        buffer.flip();

                        byte[] b = new byte[count];
                        buffer.get(b);
                        assertEquals("This is test string", new String(b));

                        latch.countDown();
                        buffer.clear();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(latch.getCount());
            } finally {
                subscribeSocket.close();
            }
        }
    };

    // create a simple publisher - wait 3 sec to make sure its ready
    ZMQ.Socket publishSocket = context.socket(ZMQ.PUB);
    publishSocket.bind("tcp://*:31216");

    try {
        subThread.start();
        try {
            startLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail();
        }

        // publish a sample message
        long before = System.currentTimeMillis(), after;
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
                publishSocket.send("NotTestTopic".getBytes(), ZMQ.SNDMORE | ZMQ.DONTWAIT);
                publishSocket.send("Not received".getBytes(), 0);
                publishSocket.send("TestTopic".getBytes(), ZMQ.SNDMORE | ZMQ.DONTWAIT);
                publishSocket.send("This is test string".getBytes(), ZMQ.DONTWAIT);
            }

            latch.await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail();
        } finally {
            after = System.currentTimeMillis();
            publishSocket.close();
        }

        assertEquals(latch.getCount(), 0);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(totalCount) + " messages took " + (after - before) + " ms.");
    } finally {
        publishSocket.close();
        subscribeSocket.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I would hesitate to expand your results from 1000 up - you're susceptible to over-emphasizing startup overhead.  Send 50,000 messages, or better 500,000, and see how long it takes.  Worst case scenario it takes 10 seconds.  Best case scenario you discover your initial test was flawed and you're getting the results you expect.

Comment: Hmmm, if I extend the count to more than 5000, almost certainly I receive a core dump from JVM. Does that suggest anything e.g. my socket buffer on the box is set too low? I am not an expert in networking.

Comment: It certainly suggests that perhaps there are [strange things afoot at the Circle K](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veaJCc0Z41w). I've never used ZMQ in Java, so hopefully someone more equipped will see your query.

Comment: What if you just use C or C++ or your language binding? Could you point me to a sample code which could yield the normal performance ?

Comment: With a quick test it seems the problem happens around the libzmq or jzmq layer. Where the installation of ZeroMQ thr and lat tests are fine, but obviously under jzmq and libzmq the thr test would hang forever without any output. I hope I could get it resolved soon.